# Solving system of equations in python

Tags: python, solver

How do I solve simple system of equation like the following in python?

x = (2/3)*y + (1/3)*0

y = (2/3)*1 + (1/3)*x

I tried SymPy but couldn't figure it out.

solved the equation part

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
x, y = symbols('x, y')
linsolve([x - 2/3*y, y - 2/3 - 1/3*x ], (x, y))
```

Output: {(0.571428571428571, 0.857142857142857)}

Type is 'sympy.sets.sets.FiniteSet'

How do I extract just the x value to set as a variable?

Got it.

```
z = linsolve([x - 2/3*y, y - 2/3 - 1/3*x ], (x, y))

print(z.args[0][0])
```

Comment: Can you show *what* you tried with SymPy?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it now.

Comment: If that last code block is the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer instead of inline in the question. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, and posting a real answer makes it more clear that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

`sympy` has updated to  `solve()` for solving the System of linear Equations. first create equations with `Eq()` method. and then solve those equations with `solve()`. `linsolve()` also still works.

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.solvers import solve
eq1= sp.Eq(x-2/3*y-1/3*0) 
eq2 = sp.Eq(1/3*x-y+2/3)
output = solve([eq1,eq2],dict=True)
```

your equations are like this

```py
x−0.666666666666667y=0
0.333333333333333x−y+0.666666666666667=0
```

output:

```py
[{x:0.571428571428571, y:0.857142857142857}]
```

once you get the output. `output` variable type is `list`. then take the first index `0`which is dictionary. then convert it into `list` type.

```py
values = list(output[0].values())
```

will give your output like this.

```py
[0.571428571428571, 0.857142857142857]
```

then

```py
x = values[0] #0.571428571428571
y = values[1] # 0.857142857142857
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy python module

Example solving following system of linear equation

Case 1:

24a + 4b = 35

8a + 4b = 94

Case 2:

a + b = 4

2a + b = 8

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[24, 4],[8,4]])
>>> b = np.array([35, 94])
>>> print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
[-3.6875 30.875 ]
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1],[2,1]])
>>> b = np.array([4, 8])
>>> print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
[4. 0.]
```